# Does Phantasmal Force Have a Range Limit After Casting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

> **Phantasmal Force**
>
> 2nd-level Illusion
>
> Casting Time: *1 action*
>
> Range: *60 feet*

If I were to cast this spell, and either I or the target otherwise become greater than 60 feet away from each other during the duration, would the spell fail/end?

There is precedent in other spells like **Witch Bolt** which specifically says the spell ends if the target is outside the spell's range, but **Phantasmal Force** never specifies such a condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 203 of the PHB you can find the answer clearly:

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless
>   the spell's description says otherwise.